# DatePickerDialog - как понять откуда запрос?

Tags: android

Есть класс:

```
public class MyDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

//Создадим объект календарь
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "MyDatePickerFragment - onCreateDialog - Создадим объект календарь");
    // определяем текущую дату
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    // создаем DatePickerDialog и возвращаем его
    Dialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    picker.setTitle(R.string.choose_date);
    return picker;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {



}
```

Вызов делаю так:

`public void changeDate (View view){
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "ChangeTask - changeDate - Метод изменения даты");
        //вызываем диалог и заносим результат в текстВью
        MyDatePickerFragment dateDialog = new MyDatePickerFragment();
        dateDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "ChangeTask");
    }`

Как я понимаю второй параметр в методе `show` - это `TAG` - идентификатор. Есть необходимость вызова этого-же диалога в другом `Activity`.

Как проверить откуда пришел вызов?

Как я понимаю каким-то образом необходимо вытащить `TAG` в методе `onDateSet`, но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно по-разному. Если задача сводится к определению из какой актвити запущено - можете в диалоге вызвать `getActivity() instanceof SOME_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME` - так вы определите активити.

Также вы можете передать к-л инфу через аргументы при запуске диалога. Используйте `Bundle` и `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle args)`.

Если же вы захотите из фрагмента вызывать диалог, то вам поможет `FragmentDialog#setTargetFragment(Fragment fr, int requestCode)`. Подробнее [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/259805/)